# How to create function for Reset Form with use kendo element and other HTML element

Tags: html, forms, kendo-ui, reset

I want create function for reset form with use kendo element and other HTML element. I create this function:

```
function resetForm() { 
  var formName = $(this).data("form");
  var form = $(formName);
  if (form) {

    //orginal reset
    form.trigger("reset");

    //custom reset
    $(formName + " input").each(function () { 
      var cb = $(this).data("kendoDropDownList");
      if (cb) {
        cb.value("");
        cb.text("");
      }
    });


  } 
}
```

Not work correctly!

Comment: What's not working exactly? http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/IqAVE

Comment: i need reset  all kendo elemet in form

Answer (score 0):

I found this way:

```
 if (form) {

    //custom reset
    $(formName + " input[data-role='dropdownlist']").each(function () { 
        var item = $(this).data("kendoDropDownList");
        if (item && $(this).attr('id') != 'AgeType' && $(this).attr('id') != 'AllAnyType') {
            item.value("");
            item.text(""); 
        } 
    });

    $(formName + " input.k-textbox").each(function () {
        $(this).val("");
    });

    $(formName + " input[data-role='numerictextbox']").not("#TopNumber").each(function () {
        var item = $(this).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
        if (item) {
            item.value("");
        }
    });

    $(formName + " textarea").each(function () {
        $(this).val("");
    });

    $(formName + " :checkbox").each(function () {
         this.checked = !this.checked;
    });


    $(formName + " input[type=text]").each(function () {
        $(this).val("");
    });
}
```